# Bootstrap Holder.js Length of "text:" string

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, holder.js

I am using default settings for Holder.js.
I want to specify a place-holder image of dimension 100x110 with text "Image Not Available":

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100x110/social/text:Image Not Available" />
```

When I do this, the text string is on one line (centred vertically and horizontally) and ends up being truncated.  It then shows as: "nage Not Availab".

Please, is there some trick to getting a "line break" into the text, so that (space permitting and font-size being correct) the text will flow over multiple rows within the place-holder, like this:

```
Image Not
Available
```

or

```
 Image
  Not
Available
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no line break support in Holder yet. I'm adding it as a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Line break support is now implemented in Holder 2.4. You can do something like this:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/100x110/social/text:Image \n Not \n Available">
```